# Confusing ActiveRecord relationship - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to design the relationships for a doctor and their training programs/specialties. Example below:

- A program has one specialty/program (ex. University Neurology Training program specializes in neurology)
- A doctor can have multiple programs and thus multiple specialties (ex. Dr. Smith is a neurologist who attended University Neurology Training program, while Dr. Jones is a neurologist and pediatrician who attended University Neurology Traning Program and Big Hospital Pediatrics Program)

---

It would seem that it could be set up as a has_many :through ... However, this doesn't seem efficient or correct when I try to conceptualize it. I have another largely unrelated model that ties in with the specialty (but not the program), that's why I don't combine the program and specialty. I should be able to access User.programs.all and Program.users.all :

### Model User:

has_many programs

has_many specialties, :through => :programs

### Model Program:

belongs_to :user

belongs_to :specialty

### Model Specialty:

has_many :users, :through => :program

has_many :programs

Comment: Does a program belongs to only one user? Or a program can also have many doctors?

Comment: A program has many doctors.

Comment: I think , you will need 5 models. I will add a answer.

Comment: And yes, as  @squadette has mentioned, you many not want to link specialty via programs. I have taken care of that in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can have models something like below.

```
class Doctor
  has_many :specialties, :through => :practices
  has_many : enrollments
  has_many :programs , :through => : enrollments  
end

class Program
  has_many : enrollments
  has_many :doctors, :through => : enrollments
  belongs_to :specialty  
end

class Enrollment
  belongs_to : doctor
  belongs_to :program 
end

class Specialty
  has_many :practices
  has_many :doctors, :through => :practices   
  has_many :programs  
end

class Practice
  belongs_to :doctor
  belongs_to :specialty 
end
```

Hope it helps.

**Update**
If a doctor can only have specialty via a program then it can be modeled like this.

```
class Doctor
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :programs, :through => :enrollments
end

class Program
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :doctors, :through => :enrollments
  belongs_to :specialty  
end

class Enrollment
  belongs_to :doctor
  belongs_to :program 
end

class Specialty
  has_many :programs
  has_many :enrollments , :through => :programs
end
```

To get all the doctors of a specialty eg neurology.

```
@neurology.enrollments.collect { |c| c.doctor }.uniq
```

Or

```
 Doctor.includes(:enrollments).where(:enrollments => {:specialty_id => @neurology.id})
```

To get all specialties of a doctor you have to do like this.

```
 @doctor.programs.collect { |p| p.specialty }.uniq
```

Comment: Thanks. Question since the doctor specialty will always be the same as the program's specialty, could it be changed to:
Doctor has_many: specialties,:through program?

Comment: Ok. I got it now. You mean a doctor can only be a specialist only if he has attended a program of it.
Btw are you sure he might not want to attend a same specialty program twice? :) At different places may be? :)

Comment: Right! So by attending a program, they become that specialty. You can only train for a specialty once at a single program. On the surface, it would make sense to just have a column in the program for specialty, but because of external models, I can't do that.

Comment: "it would make sense to just have a column in the program for specialty, but because of external models, I can't do that"
Do you mean that a program cannot have specialty_id as column?

Comment: It technically can, but I have a seperate model that needs to be tied to a specialty and is unrelated to programs... so it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: If you can add further details in the question about that, I can give a better answer. If you need. :)

Comment: There is a model Appointment as well. When a user makes an appointment request, they want to do it by specialty... the program is not important. So the appointment belongs_to a specialty and the specialty has many appointments.

Comment: Then it seems fine. A appointment will belong_to a specialty and also a program will belong_to a specialty. Both Program and Appointment models can have specialty_id as foreign_key. What's the issue?

Comment: Does the Specialty model need to have a has_many :users, :through => :enrollments? In other words, how would I access @neurology.users.all?

Comment: User.includes(:enrollments).where(:enrollments => {:specialty_id => @neurology.id})

Comment: We are coming back to from where we started. :) If you don't like the idea of keeping specialty 3 levels deep from Doctors(Doctor-Enrollment-Program-Specialty), then you can take the first approach in the answer where specialty is closer(Doctor-Practice-Specialty). In the first approach you can validate once(while creating the doctor) that only those specialties are added to doctor for which he has attended a program. 
On the other hand, in second approach every time you will go through   4 tables unnecessarily.

Comment: Bot! Everything has been working out great, but I have difficulty access the specialties of a user without going through multiple levels deep. Since Doctor has_many => :specialties, how come I can't access current_user.specialties?

Comment: Good to hear that it's going great. But I have to beg your pardon, I made a ignorant mistake while describing doctor class in second scenario. We can't make 3 level deep through association. I have corrected it. So you can't directly access specialties of doctor unless you have one more table(Practice) which is the only difference between two designs.

Answer (score 0):

Do not link to specialty via programs.

Make it so that specialties and programs are independent.

It seems like you have a good chance of running into a case where doctor has a specialty, but did not attend any meaningful "programs".

You may add as "soft" link from specialties to programs: in model Specialty add "belongs_to :program", with a possibility of program being NULL.